# Word count with java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to implement a word count program in java 8 but I am unable to make it work. The method must take a string as parameter and returns a `Map<String,Integer>`.

When I am doing it in old java way, everthing works fine. But when I am trying to do it in java 8, it returns a map where the keys are the empty with the correct occurrences.

Here is my code in a java 8 style :

```
public Map<String, Integer> countJava8(String input){
       return Pattern.compile("(\\w+)").splitAsStream(input).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.toLowerCase(), Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
    }
```

Here is the code I would use in a normal situation :

```
public Map<String, Integer> count(String input){
        Map<String, Integer> wordcount = new HashMap<>();
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(input);

        while(matcher.find()){
            String word = matcher.group().toLowerCase();
            if(wordcount.containsKey(word)){
                Integer count = wordcount.get(word);
                wordcount.put(word, ++count);
            } else {
                wordcount.put(word.toLowerCase(), 1);
            }
        }
        return wordcount;
 }
```

The main program :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       WordCount wordCount = new WordCount();
       Map<String, Integer> phrase = wordCount.countJava8("one fish two fish red fish blue fish");
       Map<String, Integer> count = wordCount.count("one fish two fish red fish blue fish");

        System.out.println(phrase);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

When I run this program, the outputs that I have :

```
{ =7, =1}
{red=1, blue=1, one=1, fish=4, two=1}
```

I thought that the method `splitAsStream` would stream the matching elements in the regex as `Stream`. How can I correct that?

Comment: @bumble-bee-tuna Edits should not remove vital parts of the question or modify code beyond formatting. You changed the given example and removed the output for that example in addition to the final question itself. I've rolled the question back to it's original revision.

Comment: What is `wordCount.Phrase()`?

Comment: The problem is that you `split` by `\w`, so you basically get everything that is _not_ a word.

Comment: .. also you may consider the `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting())` idiom (it will return a `Map<String, Long>`). If you really need a `Map<String, Integer>`, consider using `Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)` instead of `reducing`.

Comment: Collectors.counting returns a Long instead of an Integer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are in fact *splitting* by words, i.e. you are streaming over everything that is *not* a word, or that is *in between* words. Unfortunately, there seems to be no equivalent method for streaming the actual match results (hard to believe, but I did not find any; feel free to comment if you know one).

Instead, you could just split by non-words, using `\W` instead of `\w`. Also, as noted in comments, you can make it *a bit* more readable by using `String::toLowerCase` instead of a lambda and `Collectors.summingInt`.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countJava8(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\W+")
                  .splitAsStream(input)
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                                                 Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)));
}
```

But IMHO this is still very hard to comprehend, not only because of the "inverse" lookup, and it's also difficult to generalize to other, more complex patterns. Personally, I would just go with the "old school" solution, maybe making it a bit more compact using the new [`getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countOldschool(String input) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordcount = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String word = matcher.group().toLowerCase();
        wordcount.put(word, wordcount.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
    }
    return wordcount;
}
```

The result seems to be the same in both cases.

Comment: Yup, the JavaDoc for Pattern says that splitAsStream creates the stream _around_ matches of the pattern.

Comment: To me, `Collectors.counting()` looks cleaner than `Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)`. Of course, you have to live with a result type of `Map<String, Long>` then…

Comment: By the way, with Java 9, you can [stream over matches](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--), so you don’t need to invert the pattern, though the resulting code is slightly bigger: `return Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(input).results()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r->r.group().toLowerCase(),
                                     Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: One last remark: `getOrDefault` is also a Java 8 method. So if you want to do old-school counting but use the advanced Java 8 API at the same time, use `while(matcher.find()) wordcount.merge(matcher.group().toLowerCase(), 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String in = "go go go go og sd";
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //Replace all punctuation with space
    String[] s = in.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ").split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        map.put(s[i], i);
    }
    Set<String> st = new HashSet<String>(map.keySet());
    for(int k = 0; k < s.length; k++)
    {
    int i = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s[k]);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    while (m.find()) {
        i++;
    }
    map.put(s[k], i);
    }
    for(String strin : st)
    {
        System.out.println("String: " + strin.toString() + " - Occurrency: " + map.get(strin.toString()));
    }
    System.out.println("Word: " + s.length);
```

This is output

> String: sd, Occurrency: 1
>
> String: go, Occurrency: 4
>
> String: og, Occurrency: 1
>
> Word: 6

Comment: How does this handle punctuation?

Comment: You want to manage strings with punctuation? I edit the code with the punctuation detect